# eye.candy.sixties not found?

Tags: themes, jasper-reports, jfreechart, ireport

When I try to run my report, I'm getting this exception:

`Chart theme 'eye.candy.sixties' not found.
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Chart theme 'eye.candy.sixties' not found.`

Sure enough, I couldn't find the theme defined anywhere in `jasper-4.0.2.jar`. What library do I need to get the default ireport chart themes?

Comment: See also ["Sample chart themes"](http://jasperforge.org/plugins/espforum/view.php?group_id=83&forumid=101&topicid=69598).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this problem with charts using the 'aegean' theme in a web application. 
I copied the jasperreports-chart-themes-4.x.x.jar  eg
jasperreports-server-cp-4.0.0/ireport/ireport/modules/ext/jasperreports-chart-themes-4.0.0.jar
into my WEB-INF/lib   and the charts worked.

Answer (score 2):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports-chart-themes</artifactId>
    <version>${jasperReport.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
    <version>${jasperReport.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to build a project and a jar with the themes manually. There doesn't seem to be an easy library you could just include.